# "By doing sth, it is ..." is it real English?

Tags: sentence-structure

Here is a quote from the Global Times article "[China rumors fly before Taiwan vote](http://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1128629.shtml)":

> By restating these rumors, it’s they who are guiding the public
>   opinion, trying to influence people’s voting.

I think it's not a decent English.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not legitimate English? Furthermore, where did you get that quote from? It'd be kind of helpful if you could cite your source.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin What is the subject? "By restating these rumors"? "it" refers to "By restating these rumors"?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Because I feet it a real Chinese what was translated to English.

Comment: Will it be easier for you to understand if it's paraphrased as: *By restating these rumors, they are guiding the public opinion, trying to influence people’s voting.* ? The structure "It's...who..." is used for the emphasis purpose. Here it emphasized 'they',( not someone else) who are doing those things.

Comment: the linked article reads quite tersely, it doesn't flow.  The sentence you mention is fine

Comment: Well, it's not *perfect* English, because ",trying to influence people's voting" is tacked on the end rather like a run-on sentence, and really needs a conjunction like "*and* trying to influence …" But the part you are asking about is fine.

Comment: @alephzero A run-on sentence is a sentence that should have a semicolon or full stop, but simply runs on instead, like 'I fell over, I was tired.' There's no room for a semicolon or a full stop in this sentence.

Comment: By asking this question, it is clear you're not sure of the answer; trying to find answers is what this site is about.

Comment: Why is there 'they' instead of 'them'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that sentence. "By" here uses this definition of the word:

> *[often with verbal noun]* Indicating the means of achieving something.
>
> *‘malaria can be controlled by attacking the parasite’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/by)</sub>

For this specific definition of "by", it is OK for the entire prepositional phrase to be moved to the beginning of the sentence.

Here's an example:

> By doing that you made the whole crime worthless.
>   <sub>[Cast in Order of Disappearance](https://books.google.com/books?id=VxapBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT112&lpg=PT112&dq="By+doing+that+you+made+the+whole+crime+worthless.".)</sub>

For hundreds (even thousands) of examples you can search `. by *ing` (the `.` matches a period and `*ing` matches words ending in "ing") in [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) (for American English) or [BNC](https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/) (for British English).

Comment: I have never thought COCA can do regex search, excellent

Comment: @马化腾 It's not a regex search, since the symbols are different. Also, what it can do only slightly overlaps with regexes. It's much more useful for language queries. Someday I'll write a tutorial for the BYU corpora, since the syntax is definitely equally as confusing...

Answer (score 12):

There are numerous grammatical and idiomatic errors in the linked article.  It was clearly written by a non-native English speaker.  I can't tell you if this is because it is a translation from the Chinese, or for some other reason.

However, this particular sentence is fine.  This use of "it" is what is called an ["existential" or "dummy" pronoun](https://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/), and is quite common.  Other examples:

> A:  Thank you for making dinner for us!
>   B:  You're welcome, but I can't take credit. **It is** my brother who did all the cooking.
>
> **It is** true that I own a zebra.
>
> **Isn't it** obvious?  **It is** Professor Plum who committed the murder, in the library, with the lead pipe!